# Restart redis server from rdb restoring expired keys

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, dump, amazon-elasticache, redis-cli

I got snapshot rdb file from server. At the point of snapshoting there was keys with defined ttl using `EXPIRE` command . After starting server locally with the key `--dbfilename dump.rdb` all keys with defined ttl expired. 
For me it seems that there should be keys in binary file anyway.

If it can help: the snapshot was created in AWS elasticache environment.

Is it possible to start server from backup and restore keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. From the docs (emphasis mine):

> Keys expiring information is stored as absolute Unix timestamps (in milliseconds in case of Redis version 2.6 or greater). **This means that the time is flowing even when the Redis instance is not active.**

https://redis.io/commands/expire

If you want backups to exist indefinitely, all keys must be persisted.

Answer (score 1):

The free RedisInsight tool from Redis Labs has a restore from RDB file feature with an "Ignore Expiry" option. Look under "BULK ACTIONS".

https://redislabs.com/redis-enterprise/redis-insight/